# Time Ago Help

Tags: php

On following function i used 2 identical variables because inside is different language, i need help to replace this variable $periods[$j].= "";

example:

```
function showdate($time)  
 {  
 $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
 $periods2 =   array("seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks", "months", "years", "decade");
 $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");  

 $now = time();  

 $difference     = $now - $time;  
 $tense         = "ago";  

 for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)   
     {  
     $difference /= $lengths[$j];  
     }  

 $difference = round($difference);  

 if($difference != 1)   
     {
     **/* In this case i need to show me this variable $periods2 */**  
     $periods[$j].= "";
     }  

 return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";  
 }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the timeago jquery plugin? not sure why u are creating this from scratch ... perhaps for learning though ..

Comment: `$periods[$j] .= "";` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write `$periods[$j] = $periods2[$j]`, but I think making another variable is better.

```
function showdate($time){  
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $periods2 = array("seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks", "months", "years", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");  

    $now = time();  
    $difference = $now - $time;  
    $tense = "ago";

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)     
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];  

    $difference = round($difference);  
    $pText = $periods[$j];
    if($difference>1) $pText = $periods2[$j];
    return "$difference $pText $tense";  
}
```

Comment: yes making another variable is better solution anyway Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
if($difference != 1)   
{
     $periods[$j] = $periods2[$j];
}
```

Also, decade in your periods2 array is missing an s.